# How to use ActionMode.setCustomView so that it takes as much space as it needs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, width, android-custom-view

### Background

In [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager), I have a custom view, which is a title (TextView) that can be clicked (and have the background of a spinner, in order to show it's clickable) , as such:

[image]

### The problem

I tried to add another action bar menu item, but now it makes the custom view take less space, instead of showing all of it, so the text gets truncated

### What I've tried

I tried the next solutions:

- setandroid:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" for the activity. This works, but it also mean that the upper action bar rarely has any content, so it's a waste of space.
- I tried setting the width and/or minWidth of the custom view, but it didn't do anything.
- I tried to make the textView have a marquee effect or multiple rows but it looks bad. I prefer the text to take as much space as it needs, and then have the rest of the action items.

### The question

How can I make the custom view have as much space as it needs, and then have the other action items being shown ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `showAsAction:ifRoom`?

Comment: @PozzoApps yes. it's set anyway on all of the action items... also, the additional action item was set to be SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used my own library that auto-resizes text ([**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView)) and set the layout params so that the width would be MATCH_PARENT .

It's not the solution I was hoping for , but it's also ok...

It will be this way on the next version of my app.